# Add values to DropDownList that's not represented in the db and still get SelectedValue asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, union

I have a couple of `DropDownLists` in my `GridView` from customer table that binds the selected value from my db.

I noticed that if I only have one customer and would like to edit that customers gender it's not possible because I populate the `DropDownLists` with the SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM Customer and my first customer is either Herr or Frau and I can only choose from that value.

I was thinking I could solve this Problem using a Union select `select
Gender
from 
(     select Gender = 'Herr' 
      union 
      select Gender = 'Frau'
)as Gender`
 to bring both alternatives but then i get this error message  'DropDownList1'** has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items**

So my question is how can I add some alternatives to `DropDownLists`that's not already presented in DB and still bind the `SelectedValue`?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Gender" DataValueField="Gender" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EventConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Gender] FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

---

Thanks for your answers, what do I Need to Change in code behind to make it work?

Here is my code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    protected void lbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Event.InsertParameters["Gender"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGender")).SelectedValue;
        Event.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Street"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStreet")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["HouseNr"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHouseNr")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Zip"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtZip")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["City"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Phone"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhone")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Company"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Active"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlActive")).SelectedValue;

        Event.Insert();
    }
```

Comment: This can be achieved easily in code behind. Can you write the code in code behind file. If yes then solution would be easy.

Comment: You can simply bind the values with male and female at first. And then based on the database you have you may selected it by your code behind logic